# Optimising multiple join in hive

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql, hadoop2

I have 4 four Hive Tables:

```
A - 1.2 billion records and 250 GB
B - 4  billion records and 1 TB
C - 30 billion records and 2 TB
D - 2 billion records and 100 GB
```

All the tables are not partitioned
A is the parent of B (one to many foreign key relation), B is the parent of C (one to many foreign key relation) and C is the parent of D (one to many foreign key relation)

Now I have to join these tables ; what would be the best approach to join these tables

I need to create a table E with columns from A,B,C,D duplicate values in columns of A,B,C is ok

Comment: I guess hive has the ability to optimize joins on its own. It has a config setting like `set hive.auto.convert.join = true` which [not only converts joins to mapjoins but also merges MJ* patterns as much as possible](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+JoinOptimization)

Answer (score 0):

Tables are rather big and map join is not an option in this case.
If `one A to many B` and `one B to many C` and `one C to many D` and you join them simultaneously then obviously such join causes huge rows multiplication.
And this is quite normal join behavior. Say if `A` has 10 keys and `B` has 100 rows per each key in `A` then after join them it will be `10 x 100 = 1000` rows (if join key in `A` is unique) and even more if join key in `A` is not unique. This results in huge dataset on join reducer.
And I suppose your final goal is to aggregate rows. In such case the best approach would be to pre-aggregate rows to the required grain and join aggregated datasets:

```
select A.*, B.* --aggregate here if necessary
(select <some aggregation here > from A group by <key> ) A
join
(select <some aggregation here > from B group by <key> ) B
on A.key=B.key
and so on...
```

Comment: sadly I don't need any aggregation in the final result; I have to make a table E with some columns of A,B,C,D .  Duplicate values are acceptable for A,B,C

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best approach.
I have created intermidiate partitioned tables for all the tables partitioned on a common column.
Now for each partition, I have incrementally run the join query.